# How to stop a process created by subprocess.run() method

Tags: python, subprocess

This is my code, I wana stop the subprocess manully after the stdout content containning 'error' or 'completed'.How to stop a process created by subprocess.run() method.

The software LATO is created by some other people and it never exit.

I see the answer about using `os.kill` to kill child process, but I cannot get the child process pid since I use the `run` which is recommended by [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

BTW, why the subprocess module has no method about manage the subprocess...
Could any kind man tell me ?

```
def lato_convert(filename):
    ''' Use lato convert bin data to csv data. '''
    try:
        subprocess.run([LATO,
                        '-sourceDirectory={}'.format(UPD_DIRECTORY),
                        '-outputDirectory={}'.format(DATA_DIRECTORY),
                        '-logFile={}'.format(LOG_DIRECTORY +'lato.log')]
                       ,check=True).check_returncode()
    except Exception as e:
        mylogger.get_my_logger(os.path.basename(__file__), LOG_FILENAME).error('lato convert error: {}'.format(e))
```

Comment: Use `Popen()` instead of `run()` and see the docs of the `Popen` object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: In the doc. `The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle. For more advanced use cases, the underlying Popen interface can be used directly.`. I think that what you want to do is part of "more advanced use cases". Have you other reason to not use Popen?

Comment: @BenoîtZu The only reason is that I haven't read the doc carefully! Thanks a lot for pointing out. Popen solve my problem.

Comment: @KlausD. You are right, thank you Klaus, Popen is what I need.